# I couldn't decide which one to use, and where to use: simple tense vs. perfect tense

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, gerunds, infinitives

The two questions in my grammar book:

> 1)"Many people claim ------ sundaes and many towns around the world
> pretend ---- birthplaces of ice creams.
>
> A) to have invented / to be
>
> B) to invent / to have been

answer: A

> 2)It is quite common for a historic high-rise building --- into a
> residental building.
>
> A)Having been converted
>
> B)To be converted

answer: B

Could you explain?

Comment: Either sentence can use either set of tenses. For instance, there is no reason why there *can't* be people running around various places in the word currently claiming to invent sundaes. ("*I just invented a butterscotch and kumquat sundae!*"). Even the second sentence using A would be grammatical in the right context. Without further clarification as to specific criteria, there is no *right* answer and this becomes simply a matter of opinion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just as a follow-up to A.Brēza's reply, I would add:

**1)** Many people claim ***to have invented*** sundaes and many towns around the world pretend ***to be*** birthplaces of ice creams.

***have invented***:

The context is in the past (sundaes already created), but the claim was made and is still ongoing; hence the perfect tense is used.

***to be***:

The towns are currently pretending (yesterday, today, tomorrow) that they are the birthplace, which is not a one-time action like the creation of sundaes. "Pretend" is followed by ***to be*** because it is a catenative verb (?) in this context.

**2)** It is quite common for a historic high-rise building ***to be converted*** into a resident*i*al building.

Despite the use of the adjective "historic," the context of the sentence is not about/in the past; therefore, ***having been converted*** would be incorrect because we are not talking about *something completed* but about a *common practice today* in the renovation of buildings.

Answer (score -1):

Option A is correct. Think about when the action is supposed to take place. Was the sundae invented now or was it invented in the past? The claim is about the past, so it wouldn't make sense to say "My town invent the sundae." In the context of the example, answer B would start, "Many people claim to invent sundaes..." The past tense makes more sense when you read it aloud: "Many people claim to have invented sundaes..."

Comment: Thank you so much. I see it wasn't hard at all. I edited my question with a new one, can you take a look at it too?

Comment: @MabonTime again think about the timeframe when the action is happening. Are you talking about buildings having been converted in the past? Or are you talking about buildings that are being converted now? The example is in the present, so "to be converted" is correct.

Comment: I thought it should have been perfect tense because it says "It is quite common." That means we saw it in the past and now we continue to see it and say that it is common.